# Issue in Saving entities with Many to Many relation in SpringData JPA / Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have Many-to-many relation for user to role entity.
So I created Bidirectional mapping with link entity life cycle.
**Note: Role table is already prepopulated with the data by other process**

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "EMPLOYEE_SEQ"
            )
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "EMPLOYEE_SEQ",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "EMPLOYEE_SEQ"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "3"),
                @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "pooled-lo")
            }
        )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", cascade= CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<EmployeeRole> roles = new ArrayList<EmployeeRole>();
// Removed setters and getters


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public void addRole(Role role)
    {
        EmployeeRole employeeRole = new EmployeeRole(this,role);
        roles.add(employeeRole);
        role.getEmployee().add(employeeRole);
    }


}
```

**Role.Java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLE")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Long id;


    private String roleName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="role",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval= true)
    private List<EmployeeRole> employee = new ArrayList<EmployeeRole>();


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Role other = (Role) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

**EmployeeRole.java**

```
@Entity(name = "EmployeeRole")
public class EmployeeRole implements Serializable {

    public EmployeeRole() {

    }

    public EmployeeRole(Employee employee, Role role) {
        super();
        this.employee = employee;
        this.role = role;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee employee;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((employee == null) ? 0 : employee.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((role == null) ? 0 : role.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EmployeeRole other = (EmployeeRole) obj;
        if (employee == null) {
            if (other.employee != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!employee.equals(other.employee))
            return false;
        if (role == null) {
            if (other.role != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!role.equals(other.role))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

**EmployeeService.java**

```
@Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepo;


    @Transactional
    public void addEmployee(EmployeeDTO employeedto) {

        Employee employeeDB = employeeRepo.findByName(employeedto.getEmployeeName());
        Role roleDB = roleRepo.findByRoleName(employeedto.getRoles().get(0).getRoleName());

        if(employeeDB==null) {
            employeeDB = new Employee();
        }

        employeeDB.setName(employeedto.getEmployeeName());

        if(roleDB == null) {
            roleDB = new Role();
        }

        employeeDB.addRole(roleDB);

        employeeRepo.save(employeeDB);


    }
```

**Problem Statement:**
When I save the below Request body, I was able to create the new employee Sara and link the 'Admin' role.

```
{
        "employeeName": "Sara",
        "roles": [{
                "roleName": "Admin"
            }
        ]
    }
```

But when I try to link another role 'Read' to the same user 'Sara' I am getting the below exception

```
{
        "employeeName": "Sara",
        "roles": [{
                "roleName": "Read"
            }
        ]
}
```

**Exception:**

```
2019-12-12 14:01:21.625  WARN 41064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
2019-12-12 14:01:21.625 ERROR 41064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."EMPLOYEE_ROLE"."ROLE_ID")
```

Thoughts on this please.